# How to apply noises on video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have seen [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LfPWXIF5Ss) on youtube which [apply ffmpeg noises](https://gist.github.com/dericed/87dcfc43108bcb00049f) 
by these commands, but when I tried to apply them on my video it does not work

```
    ffmpeg -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=320x240 -c:v ffv1 -g 1 -bsf noise -t 10 ffv11v1.mov
    ffmpeg -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=320x240 -c:v ffv1 -level 3 -g 1 -bsf noise -t 10 ffv1v3.mov
    ffmpeg -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=320x240 -c:v v210 -bsf noise -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le v210.mov
    ffmpeg -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=320x240 -c:v rawvideo -bsf noise -t 10 -pix_fmt uyvy422 -vtag 2vuy uyvy422.mov
    ffmpeg -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=320x240 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -qp 0 -bsf noise -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p h264.mov
    ffmpeg -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=320x240 -c:v qtrle -bsf noise -t 10 qtrle.mov
    ffmpeg -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=320x240 -c:v sunrast -bsf noise -t 10 sunrast.avi
    ffmpeg -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=320x240 -c:v targa -bsf noise -t 10 targa.avi
    ffmpeg -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=320x240 -c:v utvideo -bsf noise -t 10 utvideo.mov
    ffmpeg -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=320x240 -c:v xwd -bsf noise -t 10 xwd.avi
    ffmpeg -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=320x240 -c:v zmbv -bsf noise -t 10 zmbv.avi
    ffmpeg -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=320x240 -c:v flashsv -bsf noise -t 10 flashsv.mov
    ffmpeg -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=320x240 -c:v huffyuv -bsf noise -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p huffyuv.mov
    ffmpeg -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=320x240 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -qp 0 -bsf noise -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p h264.mov
```

like this command :

```
ffmpeg -i /home/user/video.mp4 -codec:v huffyuv -f lavfi -c:v sunrast -bsf noise -t 10 videoNoised.avi
```

Comment: Remove `-f lavfi`

Comment: I did, instead I got no video , these commands aren't working `ffmpeg -i /home/user/video.mp4/video.mp4 -codec:v huffyuv -c:v sunrast -bsf noise -t 10 videoNoised.avi` and `ffmpeg -i /home/user/video.mp4/video.mp4 -c:v ffv1 -level 3 -g 1 -bsf noise -t 10 ffv1v3.mov`

Comment: Which player? Test with ffplay

Comment: I'm using VLC, but why its not working in VLC or windows player ?

Comment: They don't support the codecs you are using.

Comment: So I've to change this codec `-codec:v huffyuv` in the command and it will work, isn't it ?